# asp.net mvc 4: adding parameter to Scripts.Render path

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

I would like to do the following:

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery?version=1"])
```

the version value has to be dynamic and should match the value defined in a cookie.

How can I add this parameter to Scripts.Render  ?

I've tried something like that with jQuery but with no luck:

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery?version=" +  $.cookie('version'))
```

Answer (score 9):

Replace

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery?version=1"])
```

with

```
@{string version = 1}

@Scripts.RenderFormat("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"{0}?nocache="+ version +"\"></script>", "~/bundles/jquery")
```

as shown in this post: http://www.jomendez.com/2016/05/26/how-to-avoid-js-files-cache-script-bundle-with-razor/

Answer (score 6):

By default MVC optimisations will automatically add a version parameter to the bundle links for release builds but not for debug. E.g. when you deploy your site, the link to */bundles/modernizr* becomes something like */bundles/modernizr?v=inCVuEFe6J4Q07A0AcRsbJic* and the JavaScript is minified.

If one of the files in the bundle has changed the parameter changes on next deployment, hence linked files are cached by browsers but reloaded from the server when they have changed in a new release.

For easier debugging optimisations are disabled in debug (= no version parameter added and no minified code). If you want to override this you can set the compilation debug attribute to false in web.config, or you can enable optimizations in code, like so:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
             "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    // Code removed for clarity.
   BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
}
```

For full details see
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification, in particular the sections "Controlling Bundling and Minification" and "Bundle Caching".

Comment: Not sure why this voted up. This doesn't answer the question. The question remains: How to change the url that the bundle generates to add a version in order to reset the client's browser cache. Specifically, how to append the version to the url!

Comment: Have you checked out the link? The answer remains the same: version numbers are automatically added to the url to prevent browser caching by the framework if you don't run in debug. E.g. if you deploy you site /bundles/modernizr becomes something like  /bundles/modernizr?v=inCVuEFe6J4Q07A0AcRsbJic_UE5MwpRMNGcOtk94TE1 and the parameter is changed with every deployment, so the browser always fetches the latest version. If you want to have the parameter added in debug add   "BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;" but then debugging is more difficult, because the code is minified

Comment: @bgx: setting the <compilation debug="true" /> in web.config with bundles - did the versioning and hence the caching/busting. Thank you very much for your answer!!

Answer (score 0):

For all I know @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") is not a path. It's just name. So if you want to use different versions you should create two bundles in your BundleConfig:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery-ver191").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1js"));

              bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery-ver202").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.2js"));
}
```

Than you can call necessary version in your view:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery-ver191")
```

or

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery-ver202")
```

EDITED: On your comment: But this default code in BundleConfig is the same you want.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

Or you don't have an oppurtunity to delete other version exept newest?

Comment: thanks for the reply but that's not what I've asked. I guess the 'version' parameter was misleading... I just want to add a query parameter at the end of the bundle path. That parameter will be change each time I upload a new version of the code to the web server, so that I make sure that clients get the latest version of the scripts (this is to force the cache to be refreshed)

Comment: @Sam I edited a bit my answer. Why you can't use default code in this way?

Comment: but here you are refering to the version of the library (in this case jquery). I'm talking about doing something like adding a timestamp or whatever string at the end of the path, in order to force cache expiration. Does it make sense ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a mvc helper that changes the html generated and adds the version. The follow example works when a single file or multiple files (debug mode) are generated.

```
public static HtmlString GetScriptsWithVersion()
{
    const string VERSION = "2.0.1"; //or get the version where you want
    const string SCRIPT_END = "\"></script>";
    string html = Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ui").ToString();
    string versionParam = "?v=" + VERSION 
    html = html.Replace(SCRIPT_END, versionParam + SCRIPT_END);
    return new HtmlString(html);
}
```