# Cache holding onto old versions of TypeScript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, typescript

I deployed a new version of my ASP.NET MVC application to Azure with a changes to a TypeScript file.

Until the users clear the cache (e.g. by pressing Ctrl-F5), they get the old version of the TypeScript alongside the new version of the HTML, which doesn't work.

So how do I force the browsers to get the new TypeScript after a deployment.

Comment: Adding a file.js?{random/version} to the src attribute would be a quick and dirty fix.

Comment: Alternatively using Squishit https://github.com/jetheredge/SquishIt would compress files and it also detects changes and renames the compressed file accordingly.

Comment: I'm using `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Home/Index.js?x")` instead of src, but it seems to be working as you say.

Comment: This may help you.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075419/asp-net-mvc-4-adding-parameter-to-scripts-render-path